# Nested Http Route in Azure Function returns 404 not found

Tags: node.js, azure-functions

I have multiple functions handling GET, PUT & POST API's with different paths in my Azure Function and they all work fine. Each function has one index.js file handling one HttpMethod only & I have a routePrefix of "api" in the hosts.json. The function.json for one of the functions can be found below

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "route": "bike/{id}/like",
      "methods": [
        "put"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    }
  ]
}
```

The problem I am facing is the two PUT requests below don't work & I get a 404 not found. However this seems to work when I run the function locally in vscode & check using Postman.

```
http://<MyAzureFuncName>.azurewebsites.net/api/bike/63d51c0bb593aec8734638e5/like

http://<MyAzureFuncName>.azurewebsites.net/api/bike/63d51c0bb593aec8734638e5/dislike
```

**UPDATE 1**
I have just found out that calling the above API's using the test/run feature on the Azure function in the portal works but not when I try using Postman. Any ideas why this is the case

I also have GET & an update method for PUT following a similar signature (shown below) which both work locally but on Azure the PUT is returning the GET result when checking with Postman. Could this PUT overload be the cause for the mix up.

```
http://<MyAzureFuncName>.azurewebsites.net/api/bike/63d51c0bb593aec8734638e5
```

**UPDATE 2**

I have found that all the above PUT requests work if I use https instead of http. The other POST, DELETE & GET requests work with both. This is all the more baffling, can anyone shed some light on this.

I would appreciate any help & guidance in spotting the obvious.

**UPDATE 3**

I do not have the TLS/SSL settings (classic) option in the Settings for my function app or in any of my app services for that matter. I am assuming this was something on the old portal.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you are able to reach the endpoint with https and not with http, I assume that the error is the **HTTP Only** setting.

Navigate to your Function App, and go to **TLS/SSL settings (classic)** in the Settings section and switch **HTTPS Only** to **Off**.

---

When it comes to this section:

> I also have GET & an update method for PUT following a similar
> signature (shown below) which both work locally but on Azure the PUT
> is returning the GET result when checking with Postman. Could this PUT
> overload be the cause for the mix up.

I would say it's normal to return the resource when making a PUT request. For example, if you update the resource, you would then return the data with the updated information.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Eric, how can I access the TLS/SSL settings, cant seem to find it. Was that part of the classic portal. Also I am just returning a simple string in the PUT and its different from the GET result so seems to be hitting the GET rather than the PUT

Comment: you can find TLS/SSL settings [here](https://i.imgur.com/8XujBo4.png).

Comment: @tribal Do you have some sort of condition statement determining if it's a put or get then? If so, make sure to return / end the function after you've set the http binding. Otherwise you risk overriding the return data with other statements later in the code :)

Comment: there's no conditional statement for PUT or GET @EricQvarnström. I am using one function for each Http verb

Comment: Regarding the **Https Only** setting why does it impact only a few end points especially those verbs which have overloads with a param

Comment: I dont have the TLS/SSL settings (classic) in the Settings section, have I missed something when creating the function. The function is running on the latest Node.js v18 on a Linux consumption plan & the function runtime is v4.

Comment: @tribal I'm running the same config as you. It should be there :) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-bindings#enforce-tls-versions

Comment: @EricQvarnström I dont have the one shown in your link. I have added a screenshot of my Settings panel above.